# When is it too late to call the action wp_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, actions

I'm creating a plugin that always enqueues a script in the footer. I also have a function that if called would enqueue an additional script that depends on the other one. Here is the basic format of my plugin...

```
<?php
class MyPlugin {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
    }

    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugins_url('js/myscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null, true);
    }

    public function api() {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'api_scripts'));
    }

    public function api_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('api', plugins_url('js/api.js', __FILE__), array('myscript'), null, true);
    }
}
$_GLOBALS['myplugin'] = new MyPlugin();
```

In my theme's functions.php file I would like to know when I can make a call to enqueue the script. I've tried attaching to plugins_loaded, but the script is not called.

```
<?php
function myfunction() {
    global $myplugin;
    $myplugin->api();
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'myfunction');
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I tried to simplify the example, but actually the api function takes some parameters and localizes them. This is actually for Marketo Muchkin. The plugin has a settings screen that you add your app id and secret key. It then enqueues the tracking code for Munchkin on your pages. The api portion of the plugin would create the ability to generate the javascript code needed to pass form data (which requires the tracking code to have been called already) from another plugin or from a theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *function* `wp_enqueue_scripts`-- with an 's'-- is used as a [callback to `wp_head`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L199). All that the function `wp_enqueue_scripts` does [is fire the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L737). So the last time that you would be able to use the action `wp_enqueue_scripts` is before the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback on the `wp_head` hook.

In terms of theme templates, that means you need to hook it in before [`get_header`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header), or on a hook that runs early enough in the hook sequence fired as a consequence.

Couple of notes:

1. It is `$GLOBAL` not `$_GLOBALS`-- inconsistent, I know.
2. It works perfectly fine if *not* hooked to `plugins_loaded`. That is, just this in the theme's `functions.php`: `global $myplugin; $myplugin->api();`. I can't say that I know why the hooked version doesn't work. I'd guess it is simply too early but would have to do some research to workout the mechanics. `after_setup_theme` works and so does `wp_loaded`

Comment: That makes sense. The issue I guess I am having is that the global plugin object does not appear to be available at that early. I tried hooking into 'wp' for example. I think I need to come up with an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: It should be available. Your plugins will load before the theme.

Comment: The `$GLOBALS` was the issue, I needed to remove the underscore. Everything is working as expected now.

Comment: I would argue that you can enqueue scripts later than `get_header()` *assuming* that you want scripts displayed in the footer.