# wp_enqueue_script does not work

Tags: theme-roots

I am developing a child theme based on the [roots](https://github.com/retlehs/roots) theme. I created a **front-page.php** and added the following. I test that the page is loaded because I see the I am loaded text. However, the scripts are not loaded. What is wrong with my setup?

```
<?php
function dd_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script(
        'something',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/something.min.js', array('jquery'), null, false
    );
}


function dd_enqueue_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('something'); 
}

add_action('init', 'dd_register_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dd_enqueue_scripts');
?>
<div id="asd">I am loaded</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description that you "created a `front-page.php` and ***added the following***" and also that there is markup in that file, you are hooking too late.

You should be both [registering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Notes) and enqueueing on `wp_enqueue_scripts` but that isn't the problem here. The problem is that by the time you try to hook, the hooks have already fired. `init` will fire before your templates load at all and `wp_enqueue_scripts` will fire in the page header, which is before this code runs (or you have very broken markup). You can't `hook` to a hook after it has fired.

You need to add this code to the theme's `functions.php` with the appropriate [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) to conditionally load the scripts.

## Related:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105135/21376